# dimming leds and switches

Tags: led, dimming

Is there a way to dim LEDs?

The idea is to run them in my car and have a dimming switch somewhere but I cannot find a suitable dimming switch and was hoping some one could recommend other methods of dimming LEDs.

Comment: What LED current do you need?

Answer (score 6):

LED dimming is best achieved through Pulse Width Modulation of the power being supplied to the LEDs. A quick web search reveals several PWM dimmers available, specifically designed for LED strip light dimming, e.g. [this one on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003L4KKF2) for $8.50:
[image]

Before buying and hooking up a dimmer, though, it might be useful to read a guide like [this one](http://www.ecolightled.com/category/led_tutorials_pwm), which will help you identify which specific rating of dimmer best suits your needs, both voltage and amperage.

It is actually fairly easy to build your own PWM dimmer, and that approach is more in the spirit of this site, than a buying recommendation.

Comment: was hoping for something I could mount through my dash. Is that a bit big?

Comment: Not if you take the PCB out of the box and mount just the potentiometer through your dash...